# Prevent user from selecting a link on a UIWebView page

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` successfully loading and displaying a page. However, I don't want the user to leave the page. I have tried setting `User Interaction Enabled = NO`, but that disable scrolling too. How can I make the page so when pressing a link it won't leave the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this method, and return NO

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

That will prevent the user from viewing anything but that single page.

**Update:**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
{
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick and very correct answer. The problem I had earlier was I didn't set its delegate. The update works flawlessly :)